# Plotting Rows vs Columns in R

Tags: r, plot

Say I have a dataframe where the rows correspond to samples and each column corresponds to how often some molecule appears in the sample. How do I create a plot so that each molecule name is on the x axis and how often it appears in each sample on the y axis.

For example:

```
temp <- data.frame(mol1 = c(0.2,0.3,0.5), 
                   mol2 = c(0.4,0.7,0.3), 
                   mol3 = c(0.1, 0, 0.8))
rownames(temp) <- c("S1", "S2", "S3")
```

There would be a tick for "mol1" on the x-axis with the values 0.2, 0.3, and 0.5 above it labeled or with a legend. The same for the other molecules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try to plot with `ggplot` :

```
library(tidyverse)

temp %>%
  rownames_to_column('sample') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -sample, names_to = 'molecule') %>%
  ggplot() + aes(sample, value, color = molecule) + 
 geom_point(size = 3) + theme_bw()
```

[image]